# 3 enchanted items to cast ritual - D&D

Tags: dnd-4e, campaign-development, rituals

In planing my D&D campaign, I have an section where the group will have to find three enchanted copper pots to seal away a powerful daemon. I have an idea on how I want it to work, but not sure if the standard rules of D&D will allow it to work. Each pot has a a type of either mind, body, or soul.

Individually the three pots can be used to seal away lesser spirits or creatures. To invoke the enchantment 1 or 2 players make skill checks based on 2 skills linked with the type of pot. If only one player invokes the ritual, they have to make both checks. If two players take part, each player could make one of the two checks.

To invoke the greater ritual, the players would have to draw a basic spell circle with 3 circles equally space between the inner and outer lines. By placing the pots in each circle and successfully making the six skill checks(requiring at least three players), a greater spirit or daemon could be sealed away divided into three parts(mind, body, and soul).

Ideally I would like this to work without each player in the ritual to have the ritual feat. This is because the pots themselves contain all of the magic used and the spell circle is only to focus the power of all three pots at one target.

**Would I have to have at least one of the party have a ritual feat for this to work?**

Would this work, or do I need to do some more work to prepare this for the campaign?

Note: The pots themselves are where the spirit is sealed away. After being sealed, the players could add additional enchantments to prevent others from trying to break the seal on the daemon.

Note 2: I have not come up with a way to reverse the seal yet but it would require all three pots to be unsealed at the same time to reverse the greater ritual.

--Additional Ideas--
Having an advanced version of the ritual to add additional protective seals to the pots as part of the original seal. This would require a ritual user to pull off.

Comment: Are there any *specific* concerns you have?  If so you should add them; you explain the setup well enough, but your actual question is a little vague.

Comment: The ritual aspect of the setup is my concern. Would I have to have at least one of the party have a ritual feat for this to work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds fine, go for it.

DMs get to make up special magic items and determine exactly how they work. That's how all the existing "standard" magic items started – a DM just said "this is what it is, and this is how it works."

There is no rule that says you can only invent magic items that use the rules players have to abide by. In fact, to make unique, special, and mysterious magic items, you *have* to paint outside the lines of the example magic items.

Comment: That's what I knew when creating a standard magic item, but was unsure if multi-tier items would break standard rules.

Comment: @RMDan, also keep in mind that you get to decide who created the pots. It could be a god, if you wish.

Comment: True, my current origin idea requires many ritual masters to create a single pot.

Comment: The pots as you describe them are basically artifacts. Powers as the Plot Demands are entirely appropriate for artifacts, indeed they're pretty much the reason the game has artifacts. just make sure the fluff supports it and your golden.

Answer (score 0):

As the DM you have a better idea of who in your party might be able to pull a ritual off. If you think that this ritual is too advanced for someone without arcane or religion knowledge then you could introduce an NPC to enact the feat, and introduce some danger that your characters have to make skill checks for.

Maybe the area of the ritual taking place swirls uncomfortably with the electric feel of magic permeating through the air and to avoid getting disoriented you have to make a skill check.

If the ritual fails critically, maybe you could have an imp spawn that attacks or have temporary reductions to a character's defense.

One of the best encounters I can remember I brought out a tower of jenga that 2 characters had to make theivery skill checks in order to pull out a total of 7 blocks placing them on top of the jenga. If they failed then they had to pull out 1 additional block. This tested them physically in real life, and made the die rolls have immediate consequences.